# Tell JAXP the path to DTD file

Tags: java, exception, path, dtd, jaxp

I have xml files with a reference to a dtd file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE varman SYSTEM "referenced.dtd">
...
```

I managed to read this files with JAXP, but only if referenced.dtd is located in the same folder as the xml file. Otherwise I get an exception that the dtd file could not be loaded. And I could not find the place where to insert a handler or anything to resolve this missing resource. Please give me enlightment!

Comment: Do you use sax or dom ? Note that unless you use some entity resolver like a catalog system you won't be able to dispatch the access to your DTD depending on where it is actually found. You could use an absolute URI and make the DTD available at that location.

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties settings to allow external paths:

- [jaxp properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/properties.html)

Add an error handler to catch unsupported properties:

```
public boolean isNewPropertySupported() {
       try {
           SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
           parser.setProperty("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD", "file");
       } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
           fail(ex.getMessage());
       } catch (SAXException ex) {
           String err = ex.getMessage();
           if (err.indexOf("Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.") > -1)
           {
             //expected, jaxp 1.5 not supported
             return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
  }
```